# What properties file library should I use for both arrays and strings, with simple code?

Tags: java, properties, config

I need a Java library that can handle some sort of file configuration. I need to easily be able to store both arrays and strings to it, using the simplest code possible. I don't care if it's JSON or XML or YAML, it just needs to be stored in a text file. I'm not concerned with speed or library file size, just datatype versatility and API simplicity. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the XMLEncoder for this on something I wrote. It allows you to store entire Arrays in xml format. Apache commons configurations may be a good fit for you too as mentioned above. The XMLEnocder is nice because you can just take a java object and write it to a file. [Here's a link to an example.](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/persistence4/)

Answer (score 3):

Apache commons configurations is what you need.

Comment: I'm gonna go with the XMLEncoder thing Logan linked, but Apache Commons Configurations looks incredibly useful if I ever needed to do something more advanced than simple XML handling. Thanks!